# Determining the sampling distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let the random variable $X$ represent the number of defective components in 
a lot of components. Assume that $X$ can take on four values: $0, 1, 2, 3$. The probability distribution of $X$ is shown in the table below:

```
 X   |  0  |  1  |  2  | 3 
P(X) | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.3
```

1) Randomly pick two lots of components, what is the sampling distribution of average 
number of defective components in a lot.

2) Find $Pr(\bar{X} > 2)$.

How do I go about approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible values of the average number are  $0$, $1/2$, and so on up to $3$, a total of seven possible values. If the random variable $Y$ is the average number, we want to compute $\Pr(Y=y)$ for these seven possible values.

For example the probability that $Y=1$ is the probability the sum is $2$, which can happen in three ways, $(0,2)$, $(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Thus
$$\Pr(Y=1)=(0.4)(0.1)+(0.1)(0.4)+(0.2)(0.2).$$
Only six more to go.

Comment: I don't quit understand what you meant by "the probability that Y = 1 is the probability the sum is 2" How would this work for Pr(Y = 1/2) for example (I assume this is one of the seven possible values you mentioned in the first paragraph) ?

Comment: The average of the two lots is $1$ if their sum is $2$. The average of the two lots  is $1/2$ if their sum is $1$, which has probability $(0.4)(0.2)+(0.2)(0.4)$.

Comment: Let the samples have values $X_1, X_2$.  Their average is $Y=(X_1+X_2)/2$.  So $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=1) ~=~& \mathsf P(X_1+X_2 =2) \\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P(X_1=2, X_2=0)+\mathsf P(X_1=1, X_2=1)+\mathsf P(X_1=0, X_2=2)\\[2ex]\mathsf P(Y=1/2) ~=~& \mathsf P(X_1+X_2 =1) \\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P(X_1=1, X_2=0)+\mathsf P(X_1=0, X_2=1)\end{align}$$